# Can you help me figure out how to get these SVG's and <h3>'s to be responsive? I am puzzled

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Here is the tailwind/html - Issues arise <600px, where the text, svg's, and boxes get out of alignment. Specifically, the 's and SVG's - I can figure out the boxes, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get them to be responsive.

I've tried changing display elements to no avail, as well as height/width/margin.

```
   <main class="grid grid-cols-3 container mx-auto">
        <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
            <a href="./switcher.html" class="group relative block h-96">
                <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
                <div
                    class="relative flex h-full w-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
                    <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
                        <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_78_2740)">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.4999 12C17.675 12 18.8035 12.4597 19.6441 13.2808C20.4848 14.1019 20.9709 15.2192 20.9986 16.394C21.0263 17.5687 20.5934 18.7077 19.7923 19.5675C18.9913 20.4273 17.8857 20.9396 16.7119 20.995L16.4999 21H7.49993C6.32483 21 5.19635 20.5403 4.35571 19.7192C3.51506 18.8981 3.02894 17.7808 3.00125 16.606C2.97356 15.4313 3.4065 14.2923 4.20754 13.4325C5.00857 12.5727 6.11413 12.0604 7.28793 12.005L7.49993 12H16.4999ZM6.99993 14.5C6.4695 14.5 5.96079 14.7107 5.58571 15.0858C5.21064 15.4609 4.99993 15.9696 4.99993 16.5C4.99993 17.0304 5.21064 17.5391 5.58571 17.9142C5.96079 18.2893 6.4695 18.5 6.99993 18.5C7.53036 18.5 8.03907 18.2893 8.41414 17.9142C8.78921 17.5391 8.99993 17.0304 8.99993 16.5C8.99993 15.9696 8.78921 15.4609 8.41414 15.0858C8.03907 14.7107 7.53036 14.5 6.99993 14.5ZM16.4999 2C17.675 2.00002 18.8035 2.4597 19.6441 3.28078C20.4848 4.10186 20.9709 5.2192 20.9986 6.39397C21.0263 7.56874 20.5934 8.70775 19.7923 9.56752C18.9913 10.4273 17.8857 10.9396 16.7119 10.995L16.4999 11H7.49993C6.32483 11 5.19635 10.5403 4.35571 9.71922C3.51506 8.89814 3.02894 7.7808 3.00125 6.60603C2.97356 5.43126 3.4065 4.29225 4.20754 3.43248C5.00857 2.57271 6.11413 2.06038 7.28793 2.005L7.49993 2H16.4999ZM16.9999 4.5C16.4695 4.5 15.9608 4.71071 15.5857 5.08579C15.2106 5.46086 14.9999 5.96957 14.9999 6.5C14.9999 7.03043 15.2106 7.53914 15.5857 7.91421C15.9608 8.28929 16.4695 8.5 16.9999 8.5C17.5304 8.5 18.0391 8.28929 18.4141 7.91421C18.7892 7.53914 18.9999 7.03043 18.9999 6.5C18.9999 5.96957 18.7892 5.46086 18.4141 5.08579C18.0391 4.71071 17.5304 4.5 16.9999 4.5V4.5Z" fill="#0085FF"/>
                            </g>
                            <defs>
                            <clipPath id="clip0_78_2740">
                            <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                            </svg>
                            
                            
                        <h2 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Switcher</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
                        <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">The browser-based part of Director. Switch cameras live
                            and broadcast right from your laptop.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
            <a href="./director.html" class="group relative block h-96">
                <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
                <div
                    class="relative flex h-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
                    <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
                        <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M9.671 9.5001C9.371 9.2571 9.101 8.9751 8.872 8.6631C8.61603 8.97613 8.32325 9.25716 8 9.5001H9.671ZM12.643 10.4981C13.099 10.8991 13.463 11.4031 13.698 11.9731L15.586 10.0861C15.961 9.711 16.4696 9.50021 17 9.5001H17.586C18.1164 9.5001 18.6251 9.71081 19.0002 10.0859C19.3753 10.461 19.586 10.9697 19.586 11.5001V17.5001C19.586 18.0305 19.3753 18.5392 19.0002 18.9143C18.6251 19.2894 18.1164 19.5001 17.586 19.5001H17C16.4696 19.5 15.961 19.2892 15.586 18.9141L13.698 17.0271C13.3956 17.759 12.8827 18.3847 12.2244 18.8249C11.5661 19.2652 10.7919 19.5001 10 19.5001H4C2.93913 19.5001 1.92172 19.0787 1.17157 18.3285C0.421427 17.5784 5.56863e-08 16.561 5.56863e-08 15.5001V13.5001C-0.000131655 12.7105 0.233382 11.9385 0.671135 11.2813C1.10889 10.6242 1.7313 10.1112 2.46 9.8071C1.80669 9.42122 1.24976 8.89173 0.831422 8.25871C0.413079 7.6257 0.14429 6.90578 0.0454171 6.15349C-0.0534552 5.40121 0.0201826 4.63628 0.260752 3.91667C0.501321 3.19706 0.902512 2.54164 1.43393 2.00006C1.96535 1.45848 2.61306 1.04495 3.32798 0.790793C4.04291 0.536639 4.8063 0.448528 5.56033 0.533137C6.31435 0.617745 7.03923 0.872852 7.68005 1.27913C8.32087 1.68541 8.86083 2.23221 9.259 2.8781C9.77068 2.34704 10.405 1.94987 11.1063 1.72154C11.8075 1.49321 12.5541 1.44071 13.2803 1.56867C14.0066 1.69662 14.6903 2.0011 15.2712 2.45533C15.8522 2.90955 16.3126 3.49959 16.612 4.17354C16.9114 4.84749 17.0406 5.58469 16.9882 6.32028C16.9357 7.05587 16.7033 7.7673 16.3114 8.39199C15.9195 9.01667 15.38 9.53546 14.7405 9.90271C14.101 10.27 13.3811 10.4744 12.644 10.4981H12.643ZM5 16.5001C5.26522 16.5001 5.51957 16.3947 5.70711 16.2072C5.89464 16.0197 6 15.7653 6 15.5001C6 15.2349 5.89464 14.9805 5.70711 14.793C5.51957 14.6055 5.26522 14.5001 5 14.5001C4.73478 14.5001 4.48043 14.6055 4.29289 14.793C4.10536 14.9805 4 15.2349 4 15.5001C4 15.7653 4.10536 16.0197 4.29289 16.2072C4.48043 16.3947 4.73478 16.5001 5 16.5001ZM5 8.5001C5.79565 8.5001 6.55871 8.18403 7.12132 7.62142C7.68393 7.05881 8 6.29575 8 5.5001C8 4.70445 7.68393 3.94138 7.12132 3.37878C6.55871 2.81617 5.79565 2.5001 5 2.5001C4.20435 2.5001 3.44129 2.81617 2.87868 3.37878C2.31607 3.94138 2 4.70445 2 5.5001C2 6.29575 2.31607 7.05881 2.87868 7.62142C3.44129 8.18403 4.20435 8.5001 5 8.5001V8.5001ZM12.5 8.5001C13.163 8.5001 13.7989 8.2367 14.2678 7.76786C14.7366 7.29902 15 6.66314 15 6.0001C15 5.33705 14.7366 4.70117 14.2678 4.23233C13.7989 3.76349 13.163 3.5001 12.5 3.5001C11.837 3.5001 11.2011 3.76349 10.7322 4.23233C10.2634 4.70117 10 5.33705 10 6.0001C10 6.66314 10.2634 7.29902 10.7322 7.76786C11.2011 8.2367 11.837 8.5001 12.5 8.5001V8.5001Z" fill="#0085FF"/>
                            </svg>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Director</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
                        <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Livestream or record videos with multiple angles right
                            from your smartphone.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
            <a href="./teleport.html" class="group relative block h-96">
                <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
                <div
                    class="relative flex h-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
                    <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
                        <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                                d="M18.4703 1.59766C19.7809 1.76809 20.9788 3.2552 21.0749 5.21805V5.21945C21.0792 5.30353 21.0814 5.38769 21.0817 5.47188C21.0817 6.62233 20.6839 7.6394 20.1014 8.34189L19.3893 9.20062L20.4857 9.40684C21.2415 9.54923 21.795 9.94839 22.2697 10.6006C22.4304 10.8214 22.5779 11.0722 22.7134 11.3473C26.7591 10.8945 29.5977 9.86655 29.5977 8.67883C29.5977 7.45799 26.599 6.43002 22.3731 6.00906C22.3882 5.83049 22.3958 5.65137 22.3958 5.47216V5.47202C22.3958 5.41295 22.3941 5.35431 22.3925 5.29553C29.1727 5.77155 34.1556 7.34514 34.1557 9.21264C34.1559 10.9937 29.6233 12.5075 23.3224 13.0566C23.3358 13.1088 23.3501 13.1596 23.3629 13.2124C23.5289 13.8959 23.6477 14.6342 23.7333 15.3942C23.734 15.3942 23.7347 15.3942 23.7354 15.3944C23.7648 15.6512 23.7903 15.9105 23.8124 16.171L23.8089 16.1707C23.9014 17.28 23.9335 18.4123 23.942 19.4719H21.4182L21.2695 21.4687C26.0676 21.1176 29.5976 19.9919 29.5976 18.6673C29.5976 17.7361 27.8517 16.9172 25.1489 16.3941C25.1278 16.1089 25.1025 15.8235 25.0733 15.5389C30.4465 16.1966 34.1555 17.5898 34.1557 19.2012C34.1558 21.1819 28.5511 22.8324 21.141 23.1927L20.7233 28.8016C19.985 28.9877 18.9767 29.0942 17.9799 29.0876C17.0103 29.0811 16.065 28.9674 15.417 28.8063L15.047 23.1922C7.64251 22.8308 2.04374 21.1809 2.04374 19.2012C2.04374 17.5831 5.78408 16.1852 11.1935 15.5309C11.1721 15.8136 11.1543 16.0967 11.1404 16.3796C8.40646 16.902 6.64288 17.7275 6.64288 18.6673C6.64288 19.992 10.1447 21.1177 14.9333 21.4688L14.8018 19.4718H12.3985C12.3994 18.4092 12.4075 17.2731 12.4712 16.1605C12.4705 16.1605 12.4697 16.1606 12.4689 16.1608C12.4837 15.9031 12.5021 15.6456 12.5239 15.3883L12.5253 15.3882C12.5914 14.6037 12.6917 13.8424 12.8449 13.1405C12.8513 13.112 12.8579 13.084 12.8643 13.0557C6.57004 12.5054 2.04367 10.9925 2.04367 9.21271C2.04367 7.32925 7.11151 5.74405 13.9806 5.28316C13.9789 5.34609 13.9769 5.40888 13.9769 5.47216C13.9769 5.64794 13.9842 5.82161 13.9983 5.99296C9.69585 6.4033 6.64288 7.4421 6.64288 8.6789C6.64288 9.8605 9.42958 10.8835 13.4297 11.3401C13.5711 11.0389 13.7293 10.767 13.9052 10.5311C14.3854 9.88659 14.9643 9.48981 15.8135 9.35819L16.9323 9.18452L16.2266 8.29928C15.7395 7.68827 15.3891 6.84276 15.3085 5.88981H15.3084C15.2969 5.7527 15.2908 5.61348 15.2908 5.4723C15.2908 5.41816 15.2924 5.36458 15.2942 5.31128C15.2953 5.27753 15.2965 5.24392 15.2982 5.21045H15.2983C15.4024 3.11901 16.7402 1.60342 18.1865 1.60342C18.3643 1.60342 18.4654 1.5973 18.4699 1.5978H18.4701L18.4703 1.59766ZM22.323 25.0191C29.151 25.487 34.1758 27.0659 34.1758 28.9425C34.1758 31.1878 26.9868 33.0077 18.1187 33.0077C9.25063 33.0077 2.06174 31.1878 2.06174 28.9426C2.06174 27.0717 7.05533 25.497 13.851 25.0237L13.8971 25.7219C9.65282 26.1476 6.6497 27.1953 6.6497 28.4215C6.6497 30.0253 11.7848 31.3252 18.1191 31.3252C24.4534 31.3252 29.5885 30.0251 29.5885 28.4215C29.5885 27.1887 26.5524 26.1362 22.271 25.715L22.3231 25.0192L22.323 25.0191Z"
                                fill="#0085FF"/>
                        </svg>
                        <h2 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Teleport</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
                        <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Create a streaming service, build video apps, or power
                            your website.
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add breakpoint classes to the main tag

`grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3`

refer: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Complete code:

```html
<main class="container mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3">
  <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
    <a href="./switcher.html" class="group relative block h-96">
      <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
      <div class="relative flex h-full w-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
        <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
          <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_78_2740)">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.4999 12C17.675 12 18.8035 12.4597 19.6441 13.2808C20.4848 14.1019 20.9709 15.2192 20.9986 16.394C21.0263 17.5687 20.5934 18.7077 19.7923 19.5675C18.9913 20.4273 17.8857 20.9396 16.7119 20.995L16.4999 21H7.49993C6.32483 21 5.19635 20.5403 4.35571 19.7192C3.51506 18.8981 3.02894 17.7808 3.00125 16.606C2.97356 15.4313 3.4065 14.2923 4.20754 13.4325C5.00857 12.5727 6.11413 12.0604 7.28793 12.005L7.49993 12H16.4999ZM6.99993 14.5C6.4695 14.5 5.96079 14.7107 5.58571 15.0858C5.21064 15.4609 4.99993 15.9696 4.99993 16.5C4.99993 17.0304 5.21064 17.5391 5.58571 17.9142C5.96079 18.2893 6.4695 18.5 6.99993 18.5C7.53036 18.5 8.03907 18.2893 8.41414 17.9142C8.78921 17.5391 8.99993 17.0304 8.99993 16.5C8.99993 15.9696 8.78921 15.4609 8.41414 15.0858C8.03907 14.7107 7.53036 14.5 6.99993 14.5ZM16.4999 2C17.675 2.00002 18.8035 2.4597 19.6441 3.28078C20.4848 4.10186 20.9709 5.2192 20.9986 6.39397C21.0263 7.56874 20.5934 8.70775 19.7923 9.56752C18.9913 10.4273 17.8857 10.9396 16.7119 10.995L16.4999 11H7.49993C6.32483 11 5.19635 10.5403 4.35571 9.71922C3.51506 8.89814 3.02894 7.7808 3.00125 6.60603C2.97356 5.43126 3.4065 4.29225 4.20754 3.43248C5.00857 2.57271 6.11413 2.06038 7.28793 2.005L7.49993 2H16.4999ZM16.9999 4.5C16.4695 4.5 15.9608 4.71071 15.5857 5.08579C15.2106 5.46086 14.9999 5.96957 14.9999 6.5C14.9999 7.03043 15.2106 7.53914 15.5857 7.91421C15.9608 8.28929 16.4695 8.5 16.9999 8.5C17.5304 8.5 18.0391 8.28929 18.4141 7.91421C18.7892 7.53914 18.9999 7.03043 18.9999 6.5C18.9999 5.96957 18.7892 5.46086 18.4141 5.08579C18.0391 4.71071 17.5304 4.5 16.9999 4.5V4.5Z" fill="#0085FF" />
            </g>
            <defs>
              <clipPath id="clip0_78_2740">
                <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white" />
              </clipPath>
            </defs>
          </svg>

          <h2 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Switcher</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
          <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">The browser-based part of Director. Switch cameras live and broadcast right from your laptop.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
    <a href="./director.html" class="group relative block h-96">
      <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
      <div class="relative flex h-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
        <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
          <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M9.671 9.5001C9.371 9.2571 9.101 8.9751 8.872 8.6631C8.61603 8.97613 8.32325 9.25716 8 9.5001H9.671ZM12.643 10.4981C13.099 10.8991 13.463 11.4031 13.698 11.9731L15.586 10.0861C15.961 9.711 16.4696 9.50021 17 9.5001H17.586C18.1164 9.5001 18.6251 9.71081 19.0002 10.0859C19.3753 10.461 19.586 10.9697 19.586 11.5001V17.5001C19.586 18.0305 19.3753 18.5392 19.0002 18.9143C18.6251 19.2894 18.1164 19.5001 17.586 19.5001H17C16.4696 19.5 15.961 19.2892 15.586 18.9141L13.698 17.0271C13.3956 17.759 12.8827 18.3847 12.2244 18.8249C11.5661 19.2652 10.7919 19.5001 10 19.5001H4C2.93913 19.5001 1.92172 19.0787 1.17157 18.3285C0.421427 17.5784 5.56863e-08 16.561 5.56863e-08 15.5001V13.5001C-0.000131655 12.7105 0.233382 11.9385 0.671135 11.2813C1.10889 10.6242 1.7313 10.1112 2.46 9.8071C1.80669 9.42122 1.24976 8.89173 0.831422 8.25871C0.413079 7.6257 0.14429 6.90578 0.0454171 6.15349C-0.0534552 5.40121 0.0201826 4.63628 0.260752 3.91667C0.501321 3.19706 0.902512 2.54164 1.43393 2.00006C1.96535 1.45848 2.61306 1.04495 3.32798 0.790793C4.04291 0.536639 4.8063 0.448528 5.56033 0.533137C6.31435 0.617745 7.03923 0.872852 7.68005 1.27913C8.32087 1.68541 8.86083 2.23221 9.259 2.8781C9.77068 2.34704 10.405 1.94987 11.1063 1.72154C11.8075 1.49321 12.5541 1.44071 13.2803 1.56867C14.0066 1.69662 14.6903 2.0011 15.2712 2.45533C15.8522 2.90955 16.3126 3.49959 16.612 4.17354C16.9114 4.84749 17.0406 5.58469 16.9882 6.32028C16.9357 7.05587 16.7033 7.7673 16.3114 8.39199C15.9195 9.01667 15.38 9.53546 14.7405 9.90271C14.101 10.27 13.3811 10.4744 12.644 10.4981H12.643ZM5 16.5001C5.26522 16.5001 5.51957 16.3947 5.70711 16.2072C5.89464 16.0197 6 15.7653 6 15.5001C6 15.2349 5.89464 14.9805 5.70711 14.793C5.51957 14.6055 5.26522 14.5001 5 14.5001C4.73478 14.5001 4.48043 14.6055 4.29289 14.793C4.10536 14.9805 4 15.2349 4 15.5001C4 15.7653 4.10536 16.0197 4.29289 16.2072C4.48043 16.3947 4.73478 16.5001 5 16.5001ZM5 8.5001C5.79565 8.5001 6.55871 8.18403 7.12132 7.62142C7.68393 7.05881 8 6.29575 8 5.5001C8 4.70445 7.68393 3.94138 7.12132 3.37878C6.55871 2.81617 5.79565 2.5001 5 2.5001C4.20435 2.5001 3.44129 2.81617 2.87868 3.37878C2.31607 3.94138 2 4.70445 2 5.5001C2 6.29575 2.31607 7.05881 2.87868 7.62142C3.44129 8.18403 4.20435 8.5001 5 8.5001V8.5001ZM12.5 8.5001C13.163 8.5001 13.7989 8.2367 14.2678 7.76786C14.7366 7.29902 15 6.66314 15 6.0001C15 5.33705 14.7366 4.70117 14.2678 4.23233C13.7989 3.76349 13.163 3.5001 12.5 3.5001C11.837 3.5001 11.2011 3.76349 10.7322 4.23233C10.2634 4.70117 10 5.33705 10 6.0001C10 6.66314 10.2634 7.29902 10.7322 7.76786C11.2011 8.2367 11.837 8.5001 12.5 8.5001V8.5001Z" fill="#0085FF" />
          </svg>
          <p class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Director</p>
        </div>
        <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
          <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Livestream or record videos with multiple angles right from your smartphone.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="max-w-lg p-8">
    <a href="./teleport.html" class="group relative block h-96">
      <span class="absolute inset-0 border-2 border-dashed border-black"></span>
      <div class="relative flex h-full transform items-end border-2 border-black bg-white transition-transform group-hover:-translate-x-2 group-hover:-translate-y-2">
        <div class="px-8 pb-8 transition-opacity group-hover:absolute group-hover:opacity-0">
          <svg class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M18.4703 1.59766C19.7809 1.76809 20.9788 3.2552 21.0749 5.21805V5.21945C21.0792 5.30353 21.0814 5.38769 21.0817 5.47188C21.0817 6.62233 20.6839 7.6394 20.1014 8.34189L19.3893 9.20062L20.4857 9.40684C21.2415 9.54923 21.795 9.94839 22.2697 10.6006C22.4304 10.8214 22.5779 11.0722 22.7134 11.3473C26.7591 10.8945 29.5977 9.86655 29.5977 8.67883C29.5977 7.45799 26.599 6.43002 22.3731 6.00906C22.3882 5.83049 22.3958 5.65137 22.3958 5.47216V5.47202C22.3958 5.41295 22.3941 5.35431 22.3925 5.29553C29.1727 5.77155 34.1556 7.34514 34.1557 9.21264C34.1559 10.9937 29.6233 12.5075 23.3224 13.0566C23.3358 13.1088 23.3501 13.1596 23.3629 13.2124C23.5289 13.8959 23.6477 14.6342 23.7333 15.3942C23.734 15.3942 23.7347 15.3942 23.7354 15.3944C23.7648 15.6512 23.7903 15.9105 23.8124 16.171L23.8089 16.1707C23.9014 17.28 23.9335 18.4123 23.942 19.4719H21.4182L21.2695 21.4687C26.0676 21.1176 29.5976 19.9919 29.5976 18.6673C29.5976 17.7361 27.8517 16.9172 25.1489 16.3941C25.1278 16.1089 25.1025 15.8235 25.0733 15.5389C30.4465 16.1966 34.1555 17.5898 34.1557 19.2012C34.1558 21.1819 28.5511 22.8324 21.141 23.1927L20.7233 28.8016C19.985 28.9877 18.9767 29.0942 17.9799 29.0876C17.0103 29.0811 16.065 28.9674 15.417 28.8063L15.047 23.1922C7.64251 22.8308 2.04374 21.1809 2.04374 19.2012C2.04374 17.5831 5.78408 16.1852 11.1935 15.5309C11.1721 15.8136 11.1543 16.0967 11.1404 16.3796C8.40646 16.902 6.64288 17.7275 6.64288 18.6673C6.64288 19.992 10.1447 21.1177 14.9333 21.4688L14.8018 19.4718H12.3985C12.3994 18.4092 12.4075 17.2731 12.4712 16.1605C12.4705 16.1605 12.4697 16.1606 12.4689 16.1608C12.4837 15.9031 12.5021 15.6456 12.5239 15.3883L12.5253 15.3882C12.5914 14.6037 12.6917 13.8424 12.8449 13.1405C12.8513 13.112 12.8579 13.084 12.8643 13.0557C6.57004 12.5054 2.04367 10.9925 2.04367 9.21271C2.04367 7.32925 7.11151 5.74405 13.9806 5.28316C13.9789 5.34609 13.9769 5.40888 13.9769 5.47216C13.9769 5.64794 13.9842 5.82161 13.9983 5.99296C9.69585 6.4033 6.64288 7.4421 6.64288 8.6789C6.64288 9.8605 9.42958 10.8835 13.4297 11.3401C13.5711 11.0389 13.7293 10.767 13.9052 10.5311C14.3854 9.88659 14.9643 9.48981 15.8135 9.35819L16.9323 9.18452L16.2266 8.29928C15.7395 7.68827 15.3891 6.84276 15.3085 5.88981H15.3084C15.2969 5.7527 15.2908 5.61348 15.2908 5.4723C15.2908 5.41816 15.2924 5.36458 15.2942 5.31128C15.2953 5.27753 15.2965 5.24392 15.2982 5.21045H15.2983C15.4024 3.11901 16.7402 1.60342 18.1865 1.60342C18.3643 1.60342 18.4654 1.5973 18.4699 1.5978H18.4701L18.4703 1.59766ZM22.323 25.0191C29.151 25.487 34.1758 27.0659 34.1758 28.9425C34.1758 31.1878 26.9868 33.0077 18.1187 33.0077C9.25063 33.0077 2.06174 31.1878 2.06174 28.9426C2.06174 27.0717 7.05533 25.497 13.851 25.0237L13.8971 25.7219C9.65282 26.1476 6.6497 27.1953 6.6497 28.4215C6.6497 30.0253 11.7848 31.3252 18.1191 31.3252C24.4534 31.3252 29.5885 30.0251 29.5885 28.4215C29.5885 27.1887 26.5524 26.1362 22.271 25.715L22.3231 25.0192L22.323 25.0191Z" fill="#0085FF" />
          </svg>
          <h2 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Teleport</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="absolute p-8 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:relative group-hover:opacity-100">
          <h3 class="mt-4 text-2xl font-medium">Create a streaming service, build video apps, or power your website.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</main>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/0MfegN8Abz

Comment: Thank you Hashim! I forget you can add breakpoints to classes, and not just in the config file.